# Is there a way to have separate Excel files be imported into a Master document

Tags: excel, import

I have 60 files all with the same headers.  What I need is from 1 Master document a way to import data from all 60 files or 1 folder (where all 60 files are housed).  These are all Excel Spreadsheets - there is no code written, there are no buttons.  I just need guidance on how to go about doing this.  Could I use one of Excel's 'Get External Data' buttons?  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the structure of the 60 workbooks the same month over month? Or are columns/rows being added deleted?

Comment: The structure and headers of the 60 workbooks never change.  But the data within would be added as entered.

Comment: What would a XML Source do?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Power Query, a free download from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as Get & Transform.

You can import all files from a folder and combine them into one result table. When new files are added to the folder, you just need to refresh the query.

Most of this can be done by clicking buttons. There's just one line of code you need to enter manually. Ken Puls has a tutorial in his [blog post here](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/02/25/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-in-power-query/).

You don't need to go all the way with creating a function. To get started, you could simply paste this into the Advanced Editor of Power Query and adjust the file path:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("D:\Folder\Subfolder"),
    RemovedOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Content", "Name"}),
    GetExcelTables = Table.AddColumn(RemovedOtherColumns, "content", each Excel.Workbook([Content])),
    ExpandedExcelContent = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GetExcelTables, "content", {"Data"}, {"Data"})
in
    ExpandedExcelContent
```

Comment: Well the files within the folder will remain the same it's the content in the files that will change.  Would this result the same way?

Comment: Yes, this will work. You could also manually create queries to the 60 files, but this approach is way faster.